# Masking a dataframe left unexpected values in the index.levels

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has multiindex rows, where the values are datetimes.

I want to filter out a few of the days of the outer-level index,  so I created a boolean mask.

The masking operation seems to work -- the resulting dataframe doesn't include the days I wished to exclude.

But there is something confusing -- when I look at `df.index.levels[0]`,  it still includes the dates which I excluded.  That is,  the rows don't appear in the dataframe,  but the index still lists those masked dates.

This scares me that I misunderstand what's going on and may make trouble for myself.

Here is a toy example I wrote to illustrate.

```
import random
q = pd.DatetimeIndex(periods=100, freq='H', start='2018-12-1', name='stamp')
df = pd.DataFrame(random.sample(range(1,200), 100), index=q, columns=["data"])
df['junk']="placeholder"
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['contract'] = df['stamp'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df.set_index(['contract', 'stamp'], drop=True, inplace=True)

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['2018-12-3',:],:]

#i want to exclude where contract is 2018-12-02 or 2018-12-03
mask = ~((df.index.get_level_values(0) == '2018-12-02') | (df.index.get_level_values(0) == '2018-12-03'))

masked_df = df.loc[mask].copy()

print(masked_df)  #notice that 2018-12-02 and 2018-12-03 are not in the dataframe
print(masked_df.index.levels[0])  #why are 2018-12-02 and 2018-12-03 still listed in the index?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a necessary function, [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html), for removing these values, and more information about this problem is on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3686):

```
print(masked_df.index.levels[0])
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-01', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-04',
               '2018-12-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='contract', freq=None)

masked_df.index = masked_df.index.remove_unused_levels()
print(masked_df.index.levels[0])  #why ar
DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-01', '2018-12-04', '2018-12-05'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='contract', freq=None)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  The mask I created IS working -- the resulting dataframes don't include any rows where the level(0) value is 2018-12-02 or -03.  But what confuses me is when I just list `df.index.levels[0]`,  it mentions 2018-12-02 and 2018-12-03, even though there are apparently no rows of that after my masking.

Comment: @user3556757 - oops, you are right. completely changed answer.